# Testing angular services with controllers

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have my custom angular service, which has one method that handles with `$scope.$watch`, is it possible to unit test it?

```
angular.module('moduleName', []).factory('$name', function () {
  return {
     bind: function ($scope, key) {
       $scope.$watch(key, function (val) {
         anotherMethod(key, val);
       }, true);
     },
     ...
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that I've found seems to be very easy and nice:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function ($rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.value = true;
        });

        $name.bind(scope, 'value');

        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.value = false;
        });
    });
});

beforeEach(function () {
    value = $name.get('value');
});

it('should have $scope value', function () {
    expect(value).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Comment: Hey sorry to say I can't be the one to validate this I was just trying to give you some direction since I figured maybe you just hadn't seen the test in the doc (and most of the angular docs seem to be good about including tests even if other parts are lacking).  I'll delete my answer so this one gets attention and can be vetted by people with more working knowledge.